# Create table error in my sql connector python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int primary key, name varchar(100), salary int, doj date)' at line 1

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
con=mysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='mysqltables',database='school')
cur=con.cursor()
table='INSERT INTO pyStudent(id int primary key, name varchar(100), salary int, doj date)'
cur.execute(table)
for i in range (1,2):
    inpt_id=int(input('Enter employee id',i,'= ' ))
    inpt_name=input('Enter employee name',i,'= ' )
    inpt_sal=int(input('Enter employee salary',i,'= ' ))
    inpt_doj=input('Enter employee joining date',i,'= ' )

    sql = "INSERT INTO pyStudent (id, name, salary, doj) VALUES (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s)"
    val = (inpt_id,inpt_name,inpt_sal,inpt_doj)
    cur.execute(sql, val)
showw='select * from pyStudent'
cur.execute(showw)
temp=cursor.fetchall()
for row in temp:
    print (row)
cur.execute('commit')
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO pyStudent(id int primary key` don't you mean `CREATE TABLE pyStudent(id int primary key`?

Answer (score 0):

You adding to many values to your SQL query.

> Use  (%s, %s, %s, %s) instead of (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s)

Comment: thanks for that correction but i think the error comes due to some different reason
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int(10), name varchar(100), salary int, doj date)' at line 1

Comment: Listen, you need to specify values that you are inserting. Here is an example:

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);